# Select all records but exclude linked records

Tags: mysql, database

i have the following mysql tables with some sample data.

**1) table: ai_shipment**

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| id | booking_date        | loading_date        | container_number |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 | 2012-08-03 00:00:00 | 2012-08-04 00:00:00 | ABB987987BBC6    |
|  2 | 2012-08-05 00:00:00 | 2012-08-07 00:00:00 | BHJKKU78786GH    |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

**2) table: ai_purchase_item**

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | item_id | quantity | cost      | rate      |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |       50 | 1200.0000 | 1355.0000 |
|  2 |       2 |       20 |  550.0000 |  675.0000 |
|  3 |       4 |       70 |   70.0000 |   70.0000 |
|  4 |       6 |       90 |   90.0000 |   90.0000 |
|  5 |       7 |       80 |   80.0000 |   80.0000 |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**3) table: shipment_purchase_item**

```
+----+-------------+------------------+
| id | shipment_id | purchase_item_id |
+----+-------------+------------------+
|  1 |           1 |                2 |
|  2 |           2 |                3 |
+----+-------------+------------------+
```

basically i am storing all the purchased items details in `ai_purchase_item`, `ai_shipment` stores the shipping details, and `ai_shipment_purchase_item` stores records of items that is shipped.

what i am trying to do is, i want to select all records from `ai_purchase_item` that is not shipped. which means the foreign key should not exist in `ai_shipment_purchase_item`.

with reference to above records the result i am expecting to be fetched is.

```
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | item_id | quantity | cost      | rate      |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |       50 | 1200.0000 | 1355.0000 |
|  4 |       6 |       90 |   90.0000 |   90.0000 |
|  5 |       7 |       80 |   80.0000 |   80.0000 |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

i tried something like this (i know the sql query is not proper)

```
 SELECT 
    pi.id, 
    pi.item_id, 
    pi.quantity, 
    pi.cost,
    pi.rate 
 FROM 
    ai_purchase_item pi 
 JOIN 
    ai_shipment_purchase_item spi ON spi.purchase_item_id = pi.id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT spi.purchase_item_id WHERE spi.purchase_item_id = pi.id)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three common approaches for finding values present in one table but missing in another in MySQL:

- `LEFT JOIN`
- `NOT EXISTS`
- `NOT IN`

Here's the approach using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
    pi.id, 
    pi.item_id, 
    pi.quantity, 
    pi.cost,
    pi.rate 
FROM 
    ai_purchase_item AS pi 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM ai_shipment_purchase_item AS spi
    WHERE spi.purchase_item_id = pi.id
)
```

And here's a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
 SELECT 
    pi.id, 
    pi.item_id, 
    pi.quantity, 
    pi.cost,
    pi.rate 
 FROM 
    ai_purchase_item AS pi 
 LEFT JOIN 
    ai_shipment_purchase_item AS spi ON spi.purchase_item_id = pi.id
 WHERE spi.purchase_item_id IS NULL
```

And here's `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT 
    pi.id, 
    pi.item_id, 
    pi.quantity, 
    pi.cost,
    pi.rate 
FROM 
    ai_purchase_item AS pi 
WHERE pi.id NOT IN
(
     SELECT purchase_item_id
     FROM ai_shipment_purchase_item
)
```

The following article by Quassnoi compares the performance of each of these approaches:

- [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

The conclusion is:

> the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from ai_purchase_item where id not in (select distinct(purchase_item_id) from shipment_purchase_item )
```